# Confusion regarding the cosmological constant

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

The value of the cosmological constant is:- $+2.036\times 10^{-35} ~\mathrm{Hz}^2$. What does it mean about the characteristics of our  spacetime? What does the value of the cosmological constant tell us?

Source where I got the value of cosmological constant:- [https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1419571#:~:text=The%20numerical%20value%20of%20the,and%20the%20Supernova%20Cosmology%20Project](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1419571#:%7E:text=The%20numerical%20value%20of%20the,and%20the%20Supernova%20Cosmology%20Project).

Comment: It’s more illuminating to consider the [density parameter $\Omega_\Lambda$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant#ΩΛ_(Omega_sub_Lambda)) rather than $\Lambda$.

Comment: It’s more common to express $\Lambda$ in $\text{m}^{-2}$… a curvature value, like the Ricci scalar $R$.

Comment: wikipedia has pretty good answers to your questions.

Answer (score 6):

To understand what the cosmological constant is consider it in the Einstein equation:

$$ \mathbf G + \Lambda \mathbf g = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4} \mathbf T $$

The stress energy tensor $\mathbf T$ has units of energy density, $\mathrm{J}/\mathrm{m}^3$, and the metric $\mathbf g$ is dimensionless, so the cosmological constant is an energy density multiplied by the constant $8\pi G/c^4$.

The units of the CC are $\mathrm{m}^{-2}$ not $\mathrm{Hz}^2$. I suspect the value you quote is the CC multiplied by $c^2$. The [currently measured value for the CC is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant#Equation):

$$ \Lambda = 1.1 \times 10^{-52} ~ \mathrm{m}^{-2} $$

and multiplying by $c^2$ gives:

$$ \Lambda c^2 = 9.9 \times 10^{-36} ~ \mathrm{s}^{-2} $$

which is about half the value you cite, though you don't say where you got that figure from.

To convert $\Lambda$ to an energy density just divide by $8\pi G/c^4$ ($2.077 \times 10^{-43}~\mathrm{N}^{-1}$) to get:

$$ \rho \approx 5.3 \times 10^{-10}~\mathrm{J}/\mathrm{m}^3 $$

To give you a feel for this number it's equivalent to about three and  half hydrogen atoms per cubic metre.

Comment: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1419571#:~:text=The%20numerical%20value%20of%20the,and%20the%20Supernova%20Cosmology%20Project. This is where I got the value

Comment: @AgnibhoDutta That paper is twenty two years old, and this is a subject that has moved rapidly in the two decades since that paper was published. The figures given in that paper are now badly out of date.